# Adding time to Date Object

Tags: java

I am trying to add time to date object. I am getting date in `dd MMM yyyy` format and time in `h:mm a` format. How can i combine both of them into single date object.

```
public static String getDateAsString(String formattedDate, String timeTaken) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy h:mm a");
    try {
        return "/Date(" + Long.toString(format.parse(formattedDate).getTime()) + ")/";
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I want to form and send the date in below format to `Web-Service`.

```
String date = "/Date(12323232323232332)/";
```

Comment: Consider using Joda time for date/time manipulation. It has a lot of these functions built in, or at least make a lot of this easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
format.parse(formattedDate)
```

To this

```
format.parse(formattedDate + " " + timeTaken)
```

Comment: should i call format.parse(formattedDate + " " + timeTaken).getTime()

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i have not tested it locally but see if it works:

```
public static String getDateAsString(String formattedDate, String timeTaken) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy h:mm a");
    try {
           return format.parse(formattedDate + " " + timeTaken);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return "";
    }
}
```